# A consistent way to check types in python

Tags: python, reflection, types

I'm finding that type checking in python (pre py3, I'm not sure about the state in py3) is bit of a mess, 
here's what I mean:

First, there are the built in types (int, str etc), and the types defined in the 'types' module, where
you have to import the types module and use it as a prefix. You can jump this hurdle easily if you
get a 'name undefined error' for the type you're using, and try the types in the types module.

Then, there are the names printed out by the type() function that you can't figure out what type they 
correspond to - examples:

```
In [38]: type(Session.__dict__['mix']) 
Out[38]: staticmethod

In [39]: type(Session.__dict__['mix']) == staticmethod
Out[39]: True
```

Ok, so this one is a built-in type. But then:

```
In [47]: type(Session.__dict__['Cuser']) 
Out[47]: classobj

In [48]: type(Session.__dict__['Cuser']) == classobj
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-b062b09548fb> in <module>()
----> 1 type(Session.__dict__['Cuser']) == classobj

NameError: name 'classobj' is not defined

In [49]: type(Session.__dict__['Cuser']) == types.classobj
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-2a88e0b8e176> in <module>()
----> 1 type(Session.__dict__['Cuser']) == types.classobj

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classobj'
```

'classobj' is not mentoned in the types module [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), 
but after some search, I find out it corresponds to `types.ClassType`:

```
In [50]: type(Session.__dict__['Cuser']) == types.ClassType
Out[50]: True
```

Seeing from the above examples that type checking is not so straight forward, my question is: is there a more consistent way to check types out there that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes: use a statically-typed language. If you're concerned about checking types, Python is not for you.

Comment: If the feature is made available in Python, shouldn't it be more Pythonic than the above. And I'm trying to use type checking for serializing objects.

Answer (score 2):

python stresses duck-typing:

> if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck.

Instead of focusing on type, focus on attributes.  For example, if hasattr(a,'next') (`hasattr(a,'__next__')` in python 3), then you know `a` can be treated as an iterable.

Comment: I'm serializing simple objects into Json, and want to identify data attributes from methods attributes. In this context, can python let me identify generic data attributes as opposed to generic method attributes.

Comment: You can use `callable` to identify methods by iterating through the classes `__dict__`

Comment: In my particular case this doesn't seem to work since static methods seem to be a special case where callable returns false. I'll keep investigating. Thanks.